# Shallow copying in this program

Tags: objective-c

This is code from an addition calculator that does operations by entering the two operands first and then the operation; like "5 enter 2 enter +" would result in "7". When the user taps on a number a `double` will be sent to `pushOperand:` When a user taps on the addition button the string `@"+"` will be sent like to `performOperation:`. My question is what is the point of making those copies in `program` and `runProgram:` if they're all shallow copies and their elements all end up pointing to the same elements of `NSNumber` and `NSString` objects as `_programStack`, `program`, and `stack`?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CalculatorBrain : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, readonly) id program;

+(double)runProgram:(id)program; 
-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation;

@end
```

---

```
#import "CalculatorBrain.h"     

@interface CalculatorBrain ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *programStack;
@end

@implementation CalculatorBrain
@synthesize programStack = _programStack;

-(NSMutableArray *) programStack {
    if (!_programStack)
        _programStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _programStack;
}

-(void)pushOperand:(double)operand {
    [self.programStack addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: operand]];
}

-(double)performOperation:(NSString *)operation {
        [self.programStack addObject: operation];
        double result = [CalculatorBrain runProgram: self.program];
        return result;
    }

-(id)program {
    return [self.programStack copy];
}

+(double)runProgram:(id)program {
    NSMutableArray *stack;
    if ([program isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]])
        stack = [program mutableCopy];
    return [self popOperandOffProgramStack: stack];
}

+(double)popOperandOffProgramStack:(NSMutableArray *)stack {
    double result = 0;
    id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
    if (topOfStack)
        [stack removeLastObject];

    if ([topOfStack isMemberOfClass: [NSNumber class]])
        result = [topOfStack doubleValue];

    if ([topOfStack isKindOfClass: [NSString class]]) {
        NSString *operation = topOfStack;

        if ([operation isEqualToString: @"+"]) {
            result = [self popOperandOffProgramStack: stack] + [self popOperandOffProgramStack: stack];
    }
    return result;
} 
@end
```

Comment: is this homework for a class?

Comment: There are homework exercises for this code, but this is just a general question I have a about the code. I can't ask the real professor either because these are just video lectures on iTunesU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSNumber` and `NSString` are immutable so making a shallow copy of a collection of objects that can't changee is safe.

In `program` it is important to return a copy of `programStack` rather than the the actual mutable array. This is because `programStack` is a private internal  property declared in a class extension so it is not externally visible. If you returned `programStack` directly an external user could change it since it is an `NSMutableArray`. The `program` method returns an `NSArray` since copies of mutable objects are immutable, which has the right semantics. You want to give the external user a snapshot of the `programStack` array, not access to your class internals.

In `runProgram` the situation is different. The external user passes `CalculatorBrain` an `NSArray` to process and the class' internal logic requires that the stack have elements popped off the array as it is processed. Thus you need to make a `mutableCopy` so that it can be mutated for processing.

Comment: Thank you! In `runProgram` would simply assigning a mutable array to the passed in array have the sam effect as assigning the mutable array a mutable copy?

Comment: You can't just cast an `NSArray` into an `NSMutableArray` and then mutate it. You will get a runtime error when you try to change it. Note that `[program isKindOfClass: [NSArray class]` will be true if `program` is an `NSArray` or an `NSMutableArray` so you could put in another test and not take a `mutableCopy` when you are passed an `NSMutableArray`.